# Compiling Linux Kernel with headers (AMD FX Piledriver)

Tags: linux, kernel

I have compiled Linux kernel 3.9.7 for my AMD FX 6300 (with AMD selected as processor vendor during kernel compilation). After the installation, I restarted the system, and found that the "linux-headers" are not installed (actually I was able to find only the kernel source, not header files at kernel.org).

**The consequence:**
Nvidia graphic driver and many softwares (which depends on display settings) are not working anymore.
The previous installation of nvidia graphics drivers is also not working anymore (however if I start with previous kernel 3.2.xx, it works fine). I tried to re-install nvidia graphics but of no use. I suspect that it might be due to missing `linux-headers` which I can't see in `/usr/src/` directory.

**The question:**
From where can I get the  linux-headers source for 3.9.7 kernel ?
In my opinion it doesn't make  sense to use the linux-headers from Ubuntu repo, because I have compile the kernel on my machine, while headers from ubuntu repos are result of their own compilations (compiler mismatch?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you compile it under Debian or Ubuntu (EDIT: after rereading I see it's sort of implied where you say "Ubuntu repo" above) and then make a `.deb` package for it?  You might have made a package that doesn't contain the headers.

The following is excerpted from [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=10436):

> If I think about it - it's possible that the kernel headers aren't
>   installed because in the Debian kernel howto we create a kernel .deb
>   package which doesn't contain the headers.
>
> You can try to combine the Debian kernel howto with this one:
>   http://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_ubuntu_p2
>
> Run
>
> `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom
>   kernel_image kernel_headers`
>
> instead of
>
> `fakeroot make deb-pkg`
>
> This should create a kernel headers deb
>   package.
>
> If that doesn't work, you can still compile a kernel the traditional
>   way, without creating a deb package, as shown here:
>   http://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_fedora_p2 That way the
>   headers will be installed for sure.
>
> ---